# How does line-height property move the text up?

Tags: css

I'd like to know how the author of this style moved the heading up using line-height property? What I know about line-height is that it is for controlling the space between lines not for moving elements!

[image: An example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line-height` adjusts the height of the **whole** line, and the text must sit somewhere within that entire height, usually in the middle.  So, by increasing the size of the whole box, the visible text within that box moves up.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably whitespace / some other kind of empty space inside the container above the header, and so changing the line height will reduce the size of that whitespace, and move the text up.